# setTag() and getTag() have different values when called on the same object

Tags: java, android

I have an activity with a listView that retrieves data from SQLite database. I want to be able to delete a specific row from my screen, and for this I retrieve the unique ID for that row from database. I see in the logs that I retrieve the correct id for each entry(from 12 to 16 for example if I have 5 items in my listView), but the getTag() always gets the id of item's placement in the list(from 0 to whatever number of items I've added):

```
public class ViewListContentsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    MyDBHandler myDb;
    ArrayList<DataModel> itemsList;
    ListView listView;
    DataModel datamodel;
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.viewcontents_layout);

       itemsList = new ArrayList<DataModel>();
       myDb = new MyDBHandler(this);

        final ArrayList<String> theList = new ArrayList<>();
        Cursor data = myDb.getListContents();
        int numRows = data.getCount();

        final ListadapterColumns adapterColumns = new ListadapterColumns(this, R.layout.list_adapter_view, itemsList);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.databaseList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapterColumns);

            while(data.moveToNext()){
                //retrieve data from specific columns from database
                datamodel = new DataModel(data.getString(1), data.getString(2), data.getString(4));
                itemsList.add(datamodel);
                //get id in database
                long id = data.getLong(0);
                listView.setTag(id);
                Log.e(TAG, "my_tag" + id);
            }

        listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                itemsList.remove(position);
                removeItem((long) listView.getTag());
                adapterColumns.notifyDataSetChanged();
                Log.e(TAG, "delete_tag" + id);
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
```

These are the removeItem() and deleteData() methods:

```
 public void removeItem(long id) {
            myDb.deleteData(id);
}

public void deleteData(long id){
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "DELETE FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " +
            COLUMN_ID + "='" + id + "'";
    db.execSQL(query);
```

The bug is that this code deletes rows chaotically, I select Item 3 out of 5 and deleted item no.2 or 4.

Can somebody please help me understand what am I missing? Why my method doesn't delete from database the exact item I'm selecting?

Answer (score 0):

Here, You are setting tag to listview. which is not correct.
What you need to do is you need set tag for view in you list row item. check below sample code. (In your adapater view)

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    // your code
    convertView.setTag(posistion);      
    return convertView;
}
```

In your long click listener check with below code.

```
listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            itemsList.remove(position);
            removeItem((long) view.getTag());
            adapterColumns.notifyDataSetChanged();
            Log.e(TAG, "delete_tag" + id);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: With this approach, I get an error when I call the setOnItemLongClickListener method: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Long. This is because position is an int in my adapter and I try to get a long type. Is there a way I can fix this?